# How to delete space inside the string under condition, using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for your support.
I am trying to find and replace part of string in URLs in the mySQL DB.

I have over 550 URLs inputted in the code, where I need to delete the spaces.

i.e.:

https://www.poczytaj.pl/ksiazka/historia-national-geographis-splendor-bizancjum**, 317145**?pp=5

https://www.poczytaj.pl/ksiazka/stara-akademia-platona-w-poczatkach-epoki-hellenistycznej-ostatni-okres-bogdan-dembinski**, 413137**?pp=5

Can you please advice what code I should ran?

My proposal which do not works:

```
UPDATE `h15bpt4rj_posts`
SET `post_content` = replace(post_content, ', ', ',')
WHERE 'post_content' LIKE ', ______?pp=5';
```

Underscore is exchanging six digits, which are inside the URL.
Can you help me to get URLs with SQL like:
href="https://www.poczytaj.pl/ksiazka/historia-national-geographis-splendor-bizancjum**,317145**?pp=5"
https://www.poczytaj.pl/ksiazka/stara-akademia-platona-w-poczatkach-epoki-hellenistycznej-ostatni-okres-bogdan-dembinski**,413137**?pp=5

Thanks

Comment: How is your code not working?

Comment: Is not changing any records in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put single quotes around column names!

```
UPDATE h15bpt4rj_posts
    SET post_content = replace(post_content, ', ', ',')
    WHERE post_content LIKE '%, ______?pp=5';
```

Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

You also need a wildcard at the beginning of the `LIKE` pattern.  Unlike regular expressions, `LIKE` applies to the whole string.  You could also use:

```
    WHERE post_content REGEXP ', [0-9]{6}[?]pp=5$';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

Can you please signify, how the full code should like?
Once running:

```html
UPDATE h15bpt4rj_posts
    SET post_content = replace(post_content, ', ', ',')
    WHERE post_content LIKE '%, ______?pp=5';
```

no rows are affected.
Also:

```html
UPDATE h15bpt4rj_posts
    SET post_content = replace(post_content, ', ', ',')
    WHERE post_content LIKE '%, ______?pp=5'
WHERE post_content REGEXP ', [0-9]{6}[?]pp=5$';
```

and

```html
UPDATE h15bpt4rj_posts
    SET post_content = replace(post_content, ', ', ',')
   WHERE post_content REGEXP ', [0-9]{6}[?]pp=5$';
```

do not work. Sorry for plain questions, but this is my first time with changes in DB.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

```html
UPDATE h15bpt4rj_posts
    SET post_content = replace(post_content, ', ', ',')
   WHERE post_content REGEXP ', [0-9]{6}[?]pp=5';
```

Thanks!